# Can I stop a website from deleting back-button history?

Tags: google-chrome, history, adblock, ublock

Westlaw.com times me out returns me to the sign-in page after 20 or 30 minutes.

On most websites, I would just sign back in and hit the back button to return to where I was when I timed out, but Westlaw had an additional "feature" that wipes out all the history for the tab in which I was using it. So then I'm unable to see not just the Westlaw page that I was just on, but also anything I had been doing before that tab brought me to Westlaw.

Is there any way -- maybe using AdBlock Plus or uBlock -- to find and disable whatever causes this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually solve the timeout or back-button behaviors, but I have just stumbled across a work-around.

The upper-left corner of the sign-in page gives you a link to sign-in as a different user. But if you open a new tab, sign in to Westlaw, and then come back and click that link, it will return you to the page you had been at when you timed out.